# Why isn't my image's transparency honoured in the Unity sprite?

Tags: unity, transparency

I'm following through Jesse Freeman's Lynda course [Unity 5 2D Essential Training](https://www.lynda.com/Games-tutorials/Unity-5-2D-Essential-Training). The exercise files contain sprites with transparency. Here's a screenshot of one such sprite on the trainers screen (sorry it's so small):

[image: Screenshot of screencast in Lynda]

But here's how it looks in my scene in Unity 5.5.0F3:

[image: Unity editor screenshot]

I think that the sprite's alpha properties are set correctly, I have Alpha Source set to "Input Texture Alpha" and Alpha Is Transparency is checked:

[image: Sprite inspector screenshot]

When I open the PNG in PhotoShop the transparency is correctly set:

[image: Photoshop screenshot]

Why is the transparent area rendered as opaque in my sprite?

Comment: Ta, but I'm using the default built in "Sprites-Default" material

Comment: Have you checked it with having an actual background behind it? May be defaulting the white there because there isn't anything behind it for some reason.. Although it shouldn't

Comment: It shows white when in front of other scene elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help:

> "simply change the render queue:
>   - select Object Material
>   - change view to Debug Mode (Inspector Window top right drop down menu)
>   - change Custom Render Queue value for example 3000 => 3100
>   - now your object will be rendered before other transparent objects"

[Check here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/757673/why-sprite-are-semi-transparent.html) first as it may be something simple like the format. For example,  if you need True Color then you will need to select the format 'RGBA 32bit'.

[Check here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/609021/how-to-fix-transparent-rendering-problem.html) for more in depth explanations and solutions.

Comment: Thanks - it was the formatting. In the video he uses True Color which translates into the format RGBA 32bit in my version of Unity

Comment: No problem, sometimes it's just the simple stuff you don't catch that can be a real pain.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the section about render queues settings, as this may be misleading for the symptoms shown. A misconfigured render queue can cause the object to render behind something it should be in front of, or act as a cutout on shapes behind it, but it won't introduce an opaque white in areas that should show transparency to a grey background as shown in the images in the question. Instead, it would be worth expanding on the texture format options and which ones are appropriate for sprites with transparency - don't rely too heavily on external links, since those change sometimes.

Comment: Do you mean all render queue information? And instead elaborate on the True Color solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Image Editor is set to RGB Color Mode. Ran into this issue myself when I found out CMYK color mode was the culprit with transparency.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMq_cZmDj2E)'s how to switch color modes in illustrator.